# Facebook Login by sending User Name and Password from my Database Table

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook

I want to login to facebook account from my website, 
User Name & Password are already stored in my Database and when user is login to my website at that time using that user name & password he is automatic login to o facebook account and fetch some detail and display.

Is it Possible? If yes then how?

Using PHP.

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible plus what it does not sound right in way way. First you cannot login to Facebook automatically, second having your user's Facebook password in your db is not a good idea. third you cannot login with hashed passwords anyways. fourth if you have plain text passwords then probably you dont know but having pain text passwords of user's Facebook account in *your* database is in no way a good idea. (breaking alot of rules and good practices) Automatically logging user into Facebook is out of question, sorry. You need to rethink your app's workflow entirely.

Comment: You might want to look into turning the logic other way around: have the users log into your website using their Facebook credentials.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook uses OAuth that allows your website to interact with facebook and if the user is not logged in, they have the option of logging in. You have to program OAuth to ask for permissions to access the users basic profile and extended permissions depending on what you want to pull. Permissions only have to be given once and are managed via facebook account settings. At any time the user can reject access to your website/app. I would suggest to start looking here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/ and http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/